# What is the meaning of this directive <Files ~ "^.">?

Tags: regex, apache

We have an apache instance where none of the image files (jpeg,gif etc) are getting rendered on the web page.

> AH01630: client denied by server configuration:

The issue started around when apache was upgraded from 2.2 to 2.4.7.

After comparing the conf files I could see a difference in the following :

After upgrade:

```
 <Files ~ "^."> 
 <Require all denied
```

Before upgrade:

```
<Files ~ "^\.">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

I have limited knowledge on regex and directives but what does they mean and could they be causing an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Before upgrade: `"^\."`

`^` asserts position at start of a line
`\.` matches the character `.` literally

This means that any filename that begins with a dot will be forbidden.

After upgrade: `"^."`

`^` asserts position at start of a line
`.` matches any character

This means that any filename that begins with any character will be forbidden.

You most probably want to add that `\` back.